# Quero fazer com que o meu header fique sem margens e sem bordas. Quero margens laterais somente no meu body, Porem o body está cobrindo o header

Tags: header, css-border, body, margin

Lucas

[Whats](https://wa.me/+xxxxxxxx)

Email

Instagram

## Frase de texte

frase do email

frase 2 do email.

.cabecalho{
background-color: #070C15;
padding-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

body{
background-color: #070f1d;
margin-left: 50px;
margin-right: 50px;
border-left: 10px solid #06f3af;
border-right: 10px solid #06f3af;
color: #bfbfbf;
}

Answer (score -3):

ola, boa noite! Voce deve colocar top 0 no cabeçalho e margin 30px e auto, Assim:
Margin-top:0px; no cabeçalho
Margin: 50px auto; no body

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).